# RevMob top banner doesn't hide iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ads, revmob

In my apps i'm used RevMob sdk for advertisement. In First view advertisement banner is shown using this code.

```
[RevMobAds showBannerAdWithAppID:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
```

And in second view i'm hide the banner using the code..

```
[RevMobAds hideBannerAdWithAppID:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
```

This code run perfectly banner is shown in first view and hide in another view.

**But**  my problem is this  when i'm writing code to show popup in appilicationdidbecomeactivemethod:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [RevMobAds showPopupAdWithAppID:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
}
```

Then in **second view bannerAdd is not hide** it will still appear in the second view.

I'm not able to  realize what is the problem. if u have any suggestion plz help me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The methods that you are using are deprecated, you should use:

```
[RevMobAds showBannerAd];
[RevMobAds hideBannerAd];
[RevMobAds showPopup];
```

You can see more on the api documentation:
http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/index.html